# Start file processing from line with certain string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-processing

I am writing a Python (specifically 3.x) script to read names from a file and process them. Lets assume I have the following text in the file `names.txt` which looks something like this:

```
Rebecca Rivera
Ralph   Turner
Katherine   Green
Douglas Perry
Kenneth Carter
David   King
Debra   Johnson
Bruce   Ross
Victor  Lewis
Louis   Young
```

The script might crash at some random point within the file after it  starts reading from the top of the file to the bottom *(**Note:** this is not the issue)*. I can know exactly at what name the script failed and save it, but regardless would like to iterate my script through every name. Hence, if the script runs through the whole file, there is no issue and no name is saved, but if it is not the EOF, the name that was being processed as the script fail should be saved.

The function I am using to process the names is called by giving it a list with all the names, and is as follows:

```
def processNames(names):
    for name in names:
        try:
            processing(name)
        except:
            print('Failed. Will try in next script run')
            break
```

How can I use the name at which the script failed, and run the next iteration starting from the name at which it previously failed?

Comment: How about using `try: ... except:...`?

Comment: why not show the code and the error?

Comment: @BearBrown the error is not the issue. I have just added the code.

Comment: @Chris I want the followup to be in the next run of the script, not within

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an additional `counter` variable to record where it crashed.
Code:

```
def processNames(names):
    counter=0
    for index, name in enumerate(names):
        if index>counter:
            try:
                processing(name)
            except:
                print('Failed. Will try in next script run')
                counter=index
```

Reflecting on the comments this might be better:

```
def processNames(names, counter):
    for index, name in enumerate(names):
        if index>counter:
            try:
                processing(name)
            except:
                print('Failed. Will try in next script run')
                counter=index
    return whateveryouneed, counter
```

Also might want to look up `for-else` loop.

Comment: You need to save `counter` somewhere outside the function, so it's not reset to zero when the function is called again.

Comment: @zabop that does the job. Thank you!

Comment: This will set up a `counter` to the *last* failing name index. If you need one by one - you need to add a `break`. Also - counter is neither returned nor visible outside of the function.

Comment: @phoenix is correct about `break`. Also, you probably want `index >= counter` to retry the failed name rather than skip over it.